# How to save site on Django from sql injections with slug

Tags: python, django

I use **Django 1.7.6** and I have many **slug** fields in my models.

For example, I have url like so:

```
blog/post-about-cars
```

and in urls.py:

```
url(r'^blog/(?P<slug>.+)/$', PostDetail.as_view(), name='post'),
```

How to save site from sql-injections?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django's generic views use the ORM without any manipulation with SQL code.  So you are already safe from SQL-injection.

Just a note: slugs usually matched by the following regex:

```
url(r'^blog/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', PostDetail.as_view(), name='post'),
```